# Нужно создать метод, который выводит массив

Tags: java, массивы, методы

Нужно создать метод, который выводит массив, у меня выводит непонятный набор символов `-[I@4554617c`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = new int[]{15, 3, 21, 11};
    System.out.println(task4(arr));
}

public static int[] task4(int arr[]) {
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(task4(arr)));
```

Для всех классов массивов по умолчанию не переопределён метод `toString`, и вызывается дефолтный метод класса `Object`, результат вывода которого вы и увидели.

Либо вручную итерируйтесь по массиву и выводите его, либо используйте встроенные в JDK возможности — например, метод `Arrays.toString`, который я использовал в примере в начале ответа.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int arr[] = new int[] {15,3,21,11};
        task4(arr);
    }

    public static void task4(int[] arr){
        for(int i : arr){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D)):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[]{15, 3, 21, 11};
    System.out.println(task4(arr)); // [15, 3, 21, 11]
}

public static String task4(int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.toString(arr);
}
```